# Quelle für Abgrenzung von Synonymen für das heutige Deutsch

Tags: synonym, resource

Ich suche eine gute Quelle für die Unterscheidung von Synonymen. Bei meinen Internetrecherchen bin ich des Öfteren auf das "Synonymische Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache" von Johann August Eberhards gestoßen:

http://www.textlog.de/synonym.html

Leider ist dies jedoch von 1910 und daher nicht mehr ganz aktuell. Kann mir jemand ein vergleichbares Werk für das heutige Deutsch nennen?

Zur Klarstellung: es geht mir nicht darum, Synonyme zu *finden*, sondern die *Abgrenzungen* zwischen Synonymen zu verstehen.

**Ergänzung:**

Es muss natürlich nicht unbedingt ein Printmedium sein, eine qualitative Onlinequelle wäre ebenso ausreichend.

Comment: Sind dir die Einteilungen in Gruppen, wie ich sie in meiner Antwort beschrieben habe, nicht Abgrenzung genug? Falls nein: Was genau verstehst du unter "Abgrenzung"?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich suche ein Werk, dass nicht die verschiedenen Bedeutungen *eines* Wortes erläutert (Teekesselchen), sondern die Differenzen zwischen zwei oder mehreren verschiedenen, *synonymen* Wörtern.

Comment: Siehe zB mal folgenden Artikel aus dem o.g. Werk von 1910: http://www.textlog.de/37701.html

Comment: hast du bei woxicon auch, nur kompakter: http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/körper.php und http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/leib.php Und so nebenbei wird dir auch noch eine ganze Reihe weiterer Synonyme mitgeliefert.

Comment: Das reicht mir nicht. Unter Abgrenzungen verstehe ich (u.a.), welche exakten Bedeutungsunterschiede es zwischen Synonymen gibt und wann man welches Wort verwendet. Nochmal: Synonyme finden ist kein Problem, aber wissen, wann man welches Wort verwendet, schon.

Comment: Was du suchst ist demnach kein Wörterbuch, sondern ein Lexikon. Das wonach du gefragt hast (und worauf ich geantwortet habe) ist nicht das was du eigentlich wissen wolltest. **Wörterbuch**: Ein Buch, in dem **Wörter** (Bausteine einer Sprache) aufgelistet sind, und in dem erläutert wird, in welchem ***sprachlichen*** Kontext man sie benutzt. **Lexikon**: Ein Buch in dem **Begriffe** (sinntragende Elemente) aufgelistet sind, und in dem deren ***Bedeutung*** beschrieben wird. Ein Wörterbuch ist nicht dazu da, Bedeutungen von Begriffen darzustellen, sondern den Gebrauch von Wörtern kund zu tun.

Comment: Darüber kann man sich vielleicht streiten, aber wie dem auch sei: ich habe den Titel geändert.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt eine sehr gute Internetseite für die Suche nach Synonymen:

http://synonyme.woxikon.de

Wenn du dort z.B. nach einem Synonym für »Läufer« suchst, werden die Synonyme in vier Gruppen geordnet angezeigt:

> 1. Bedeutung: **Matte** [n]
>      Brücke, Teppich, Zierdecke, Läufer
> 2. Bedeutung: **Sprinter** [n]
>      Renner, jemand der läuft, Mitläufer, Läufer
> 3. Bedeutung: **Schachfigur** [n]
>      Schachfigur, Läufer
> 4. Bedeutung: **Fußabtreter** [n]
>      Türvorleger, Fußabstreicher, Läufer, Teppich, Türvorlage, Vorleger, Matte

Bei der Suche nach »Leiter« werden sogar 17 verschiedene Bedeutungsgruppen angezeigt.

Comment: Das Woxikon nutze ich schon seit geraumer Zeit. War bisher sehr zufrieden damit.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube, das [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/) ist für solche Zwecke am besten geeignet.

Answer (score 0):

Ein Synonymenwörterbuch wird an dieser Stelle nicht weiterhelfen, weil dort nur die Synonyme genannt werden. Mögliche Alternativen sind m. E.:

- ein richtig dickes deutsches Wörterbuch, das außer der Pluralform und Deklination auch einen erklärenden Text anbietet
- ein Wörterbuch *Deutsch als Fremdsprache*, da sollte man sich zumindest einmal die Werke von Langenscheidt, Pons oder Wahrig angucken.